# Несколько ориентаций только одного экрана

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Необходимо показать экран в приложении с поддержкой нескольких ориентаций (portrait + landscape), структура экранов такая: UINavigationController -> UITabBarViewController -> UINavigationController  -> UIViewController, с которого идет present необходимого контроллера. Идеальным был бы вариант, где поведение было бы похоже на AVPlayerViewController, в котором независимо от настроек приложения есть поддержка разных ориентаций. Собственно, во всем приложении используется только одна ориентация - portrait, а для показываемого контроллера нужно еще добавить вариант с landscape. Как это сделать так, чтобы не поломать приложение в текущем виде?

Пока попытался прописать в Info.plist необходимые режимы и зафиксировать supportedInterfaceOrientations и shouldAutorotate через такие костыли:

```
extension UITabBarController {
    open override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return selectedViewController?.shouldAutorotate ?? false
    }
    
    open override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return selectedViewController?.supportedInterfaceOrientations ?? .portrait
    }
}

extension UINavigationController {
    open override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return topViewController?.shouldAutorotate ?? false
    }
    
    open override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return topViewController?.supportedInterfaceOrientations ?? .portrait
    }
}
```

Соответственно, в нужном мне контроллере я переписываю эти два свойства и там все работает, но если я сделаю dismiss этого контроллера в landscape ориентации, то она сохранится для родительского контроллера и он не будет далее поворачиваться (нужно сделать так, чтобы ориентация верхнего контроллера сохранялась при закрытии текущего). Более того, если при открытии приложения телефон находится в landscape моде, то LaunchScreen запустится в нем и интерфейс приложения сильно "преображается" (statusBar в landscape, а сам экран в portrait моде, с размерами интерфейса происходит что-то странное и т.д.). Полагаю, делаю что-то неправильно, так что ищу решение этой проблемы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил эту проблему, найдя нужную информацию по кусочкам. Итак, для того, чтобы получить желаемое, нужно:

1. В Info.plist в Supported interface orientations указываем только Portrait
2. В AppDelegate я добавил следующие методы:

   ```
    func topController(for controller: UIViewController) -> UIViewController {
        if let controller = controller as? UINavigationController {
            if let controller = controller.topViewController, !controller.isBeingDismissed {
                return topController(for: controller)
            }
            return controller
        } else if let controller = controller as? UITabBarController {
            if let controller = controller.selectedViewController, !controller.isBeingDismissed {
                return topController(for: controller)
            }
            return controller
        } else if let controller = controller.presentedViewController, !controller.isBeingDismissed {
            return topController(for: controller)
        } else {
            return controller
        }
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        if let rootController = window?.rootViewController {
            return topController(for: rootController).supportedInterfaceOrientations
        }
        return .portrait
    }
   ```

В нужном контроллере прописываю необходимые `supportedInterfaceOrientations` и `shouldAutorotate` = true.

Результат следующий: приложение запускается в портретном режиме (включая splash screen и независимо от текущей ориентации экрана). При переходе на нужный экран в случае смены ориентации, ориентация экрана также меняется (даже, если пользователь повернул экран перед его открытием), при этом родительский экран это никак не затрагивает, кроме момент одного момента. Если ориентация экрана портретная, а телефон повернут в альбомной ориентации, при открытии экрана с поддержкой альбомной ориентации, он повернет новый экран как надо, однако из-за поворота статусбара будет сдвиг родительского экрана вверх и вбок (было бы неплохо как-то избавиться от этого эффекта, но увы, пока не знаю как).